# NSURLRequest cache policy enum

Tags: objective-c, caching, enums, nsurlrequest

I'm creating a url request as follows:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:1 timeoutInterval:5];
```

Referring to the developer documentation for the cache policy, I read the following:

```
enum
{
   NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy = 0,
   NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData = 1,
   NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData =4,
   NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData,
   NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad = 2,
   NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataDontLoad = 3,
   NSURLRequestReloadRevalidatingCacheData = 5
};
typedef NSUInteger NSURLRequestCachePolicy;
```

So what is the proper way to declare the `cachePolicy` for the `NSURLRequest`?

Shall I define it as:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:1 timeoutInterval:5];
```

Or shall I define it as:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:5];
```

Both seem to work but is one approach better than the other?

Comment: thanks for posting this on SO..I take it you already new the answer to your own question...

Comment: @whyoz I sort of knew the answer. I just didn't fully understand what I was doing.

Comment: Nobody here "fully" understands what they're doing!  Haha..it's posts like this that help all of us that would rather search here than dive into Apple docs that don't lay it out cut and dry like you did for us.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second approach is better because you can then easily look at your code later on (e.g. a few weeks after you last looked at it) and say "ah, this request will always reload while ignoring the local cache".  Otherwise, you'll have to do some research to figure out what that mysterious "`1`" means.

Comment: +1; using the named constants is (almost?) always the way to go.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Good point. Just wanted to clarify the use of `enums` for such situations. Thank you.